# REST response code for successful add but failed to return the created object

Tags: php, api, rest, status

Okay. I am wondering what is the possible HTTP Status (response) code in this scenario.

Lets say, `POST /Student/` creates a student resource. Assume that, there are multiple tables to update. `Student` resource is created.

Usually, when a resource is created, the resource should be returned immediately in the response with `200 Successful`.

However, assume that the resource is created, but when you try to pull the resource (a query from database) fails. What status code should we return?

```
   `201 Created`? (No resource)
   '200 Successful`? but without the resource. 
   `500 Internal Server Error`?
```

Something else?

I guess its fairly a common scenario.

**EDIT**

I want to clarify this. 
First thing, its all ONE POST call to create a resource.
The response should be `200` with the resource object as JSON.
But there is an error **only** during the retrieval of the resource (the resource was created successfully).

The reasons for failure to get the resource form the database might be intermittent and might be server / network related and could be identified and fixed later. But the resource was created for sure successfully.

Comment: If a query fails I would say 500; if a query has no results, 404.

Comment: But how does the client know if the resource was created, if we return 500?

Comment: Also why not returning `201 Created` at creation time?

Comment: Let's put it another way, if the resource is created, why are you not returning it? Doesn't that constitute as server failure? In fact, if you ran it inside a transaction, you would abort it for whatever error and then return 500.

Comment: I mentioned the possible reason in my comment to @iserni

Comment: You have to be more specific about what you think can go wrong at which time.

Comment: If the resource *was* created, then a 200 *must* be returned. If the resource was not created, a 500 must be returned. Then the client will know that an error occurred. It is architecturally wrong to lie to your clients. 200 must be sent if, **and only if**, the resource has been created as the client expects. Anything else is begging for troubles, and troubles can be trusted to hear you and come in droves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go with `201 Created`, as [it doesn't mandate to return the created entity](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.2.2). If the client tries to retrieve it, it'll get a `500 Server Error`.

If you want to let the client know of a possible server shenanigan, you could return `202 Accepted`, as [it is non-committal](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.2.3).

Whatever you do, I suggest you make this resource idempotent because it seems it has complex failure modes and the client is likely to re-attempt a create.

Comment: Wait, the 201 actually *does* require to return the created entity (if not the variant). And using 202 to notify of a possible mishap is sort of twisting the protocol... the client must have been *expecting* a 202, i.e. it has to know it is submitting a "batch" request. 202 is not to be used as a sort of "oopsie" code - or that's my interpretation, anyway...

Comment: "The response SHOULD include an entity containing a list of resource characteristics and location(s) from which the user or user agent can choose the one most appropriate." <- Doesn't sound like returning the created entity. I agree that my suggestion to use `202` if it's created but not immediately readable can be viewed as twisting the original intent ("the action cannot be carried out immediately").

Answer (score 2):

> assume that the resource is created, but when you try to pull the resource (a query from database) fails

Then the resource has **not** been created. It only *appeared* to have been. And this is certainly a server-side error, therefore a 5xx code.

Unless there were user-supplied parameters that brought on the failure, in which case it would be a 4xx code.

*Update*: or if I misunderstood, and you mean that the creation was OK and returned a resource ID, and then the resource was not found later on by a subsequent and valid `GET` query, well, in that case you have something broken in the server code and you *should have* issued a 5xx error earlier. A workaround could be to create the resource, issue the query from the resource-creating code, and either return 200 or do a cleanup, a retry, or a 5xx return if it failed. But what really ought to be done is to look into whatever caused the resource to disappear or to *only seem* to have been created (e.g. concurrency problems, bad transaction management, caches...).

### A Complex Scenario

The REST service requests for a resource to be created and the server accepts the request. The server itself routes the request to a backend, let's say a database, which returns (to the server) "OK" and a resource ID. Then the server, just in case, *checks*, and asks for resource ID. And the database responds, 'no such resource'.

In this case the server cannot in good conscience return a 200 code and a resource ID to its client, not when it has good reason to suspect that the client will run into troubles if it tries to use that resource ID. And the error later on might be much more difficult to catch: maybe the client has sent emails or undertaken complex actions involving that ID.

Therefore either a 500 is returned, or the server can attempt to fix the situation, applying one or more of the following, as appropriate and possible:

- wait a short time (the client is still waiting!) and check for resource reappearance
- try flushing caches or otherwise prodding the database into coughing up the resource
- invalidate the resource
- delete the resource (even if apparently it does not exist)
- log the error and send the details to the administrator
- repeat resource creation a given number of times (not too large, or we may snowball a transient problem into a self-denial-of-service) until it works

If the situation is fixed within a reasonable and tolerable (by the client) time, then the working resource can be returned with code 200.

Of course, the reason why all the above actually happened will have to be investigated and remedied. Possibly, some "orphan" resources might have to be periodically purged from the database (always an awkward proposition).

Comment: Assume that, there was connection issue Or Server timeout. There could be several reasons, not necessary not created.

Comment: Even if it has been created but the query fails for any reason, it's still a server error (5xx) not a user error (4xx).

Comment: Then how does the client know if resource was created?

Comment: Didn't it get a `2xx` in the first place?

Comment: The problem is elsewhere: how does *the server* know if the resource was created? "Know" as in, *be sure that*?

Comment: Like knowing a DB write succeeded? This is quite far from a REST API question then.

Comment: @DavidDossot Its a REST response question. The underlying cause could be later found and updated. Or the problem might be intermittent. The question is, in that case, What status code should the client get 'resource created, but the problem retrieving it? Its all in one requet

Comment: I've tried to elaborate on the problem. Basically, however, my personal rule of thumb is *never gloss over a problem with your clients*. If the problem has been solved/remedied then it's OK to not mention the fact that it happened (to the client. You still need to notify the sysadmin). But returning a "suspicious" resource (or "relaxing" resource tests to have fewer suspicions) isn't something I'd recommend doing. I'd rather scream bloody murder and issue a 500 error :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are wrong when you state:

> The response should be 200 with the resource object as JSON.

The response should be **`201`** not `200` and a `Location:` header should be set. There is no need to include the resource representation in the response. If you want to include it, and your code looks something like this:

```
mysql_query('INSERT ...'); // succeeds
$id = mysql_insert_id(); // succeeds
$result = mysql_query('SELECT ...'); // times out
```

Then just return 201 with no body. The client can try again to get the created resource if it wants it.

Comment: I read David's answer and just felt more needed to be added. Everything he said is correct too :) 5xx is only correct if the `INSERT` query fails, but the params POSTed look okay. Obviously incorrect user-supplied params should cause your code to bail with a 4xx before it ever gets to the INSERT.